How to style Angular parent and child component
I'm learning Angular 18 while I already know React. I have a "pretty big" HTML file, which I would like to split. Let's take this pseudo and minified example:
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
  <li>This is Angular</li>
</ul>

# simple applied CSS
ul {
  display: flex;
}


Now let's suppose I want to create a new component which is called <list> which contains all the three <li> elements, like:
# list.component.html
<li>Hello</li>
<li>World</li>
<li>This is Angular</li>

# parent-of-list.component.html
<ul>
  <list />
</ul>

# which will render the actual DOM as...
<ul>
  <list-comp>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
    <li>This is Angular</li>
  </list-comp>
</ul>


The flexbox style I wrote before is broken, because the <list> selector is rendered, therefore the flex-box is applied to the <list> element and not to the <li>. In React I used the fragment, and in Angular I just read about <ng-container>, but after a couple of tries it seemd to not working properly.
I know that seems a non-sense example, but just take it as a minified one. In this project I have to extract for example a row of a table, rendering it in two different ways, therefore I wanted to use two different component for each one, but then, the style is broken.
Other example, using bootstrap:
<div class="row>
  @for(...) {
    <div class="col">Item</div>
  }
</div>

Let's suppose I want to create a card, at the place of the col element. Then the <Card /> element would render an element too much if the HTML file would be:
<div class="col">
   Item
</div>

Anyone can clarify how to "think" about it? I would appreciate a solution, but most an explaination to grasp the concept. I have already read style-guide and docs, I also googled, but I am not satisfied.

You can simply use the different angular component selectors.

[selector] -> Attribute selector. (<li selector></li>)
.selector -> class selector. (<li class="selector"></li>)
selector -> component selector. (<selector></selector>)

The advantage of attribute and component selectors is that there is no angular tags inserted.
Full Code:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: '.li-comp',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <ng-content/>
  `,
})
export class LiComp {
  @Input() text!: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [LiComp],
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li class="li-comp">Hello</li>
      <li class="li-comp">World</li>
      <li class="li-comp">This is Angular</li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Hi, I edited the question, because I think it was not completely clear what I meant; or maybe I did not understand your suggestion at all, sorry

@ncasteln This is a solution where the selector does not need to be an element, but still be a component hence it wont break your CSS since there is no extra element generated, If you have two component you need to conditionally render them, like @if(someCondition) { <comp-one/> } @else { <comp-two/>, if using older version of angular *ngIf head over to angular.dev try the examples to get comfortable with angular

You can fix your layout by applying the style display: contents to the host of the child component:
/* list-comp.component.css */
:host {
  display: contents;
}


I think you just need to use <ng-container> in your <list> component to wrap all 3 <li> tags like below:
<ng-container>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
  <li>This is Angular</li>
</ng-container>

in your parent-of-list.component.html you can include <list> like below:
<ul>
  <list />
</ul>

in actual DOM it will render like below:
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
  <li>This is Angular</li>
</ul>

ng-container allows you to maintain a HTML structure in Angular but it will not render in actual DOM when check your site on browser. I think it is similar to React fragment.
This way your <li> tags will render as direct children of <ul> and your display: flex; will also work as aspected on all <li> element.
Updated:
You can check example setup from below link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/playground-angular-17-material-nsu3nd-ueh2pq?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist%2Flist.component.css
In the list component, I have used the display: contents; for :host CSS property. This property does not remove the list tag from the DOM; instead, it makes the element's children behave as if they were direct children of the parent element, effectively ignoring the element itself.
so you just need to add below css in your list component:
:host {
  display: contents;
}


Well, I thought the same as you, but it doesn't work. The  element is still rendered in the DOM and the display property is not applied correctly.

I have updated answer and also created stackblitz setup for this scenario. You can check it and try to apply solution.

After a couple days of researching I would resume the possible solutions:
1) :host selector
Like @Dixit and @JSON Derulo posted, is it possible to use the :host selector to display: content, or by adding the required style we want to use in the host HTML element.
2) host {...} properties
In the Angular 18 official docs they talk about this topic pretty explicitly. I suggest also this ng-conf video which is about exactly the problem of having a DOM with too many not-required elements.
At the end the practical solution I needed was something like:
@Component({
  selector: 'helloworld',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './helloworld.component.html',
  styleUrl: './helloworld.component.scss',
  host: {
    '[class.hello-1]': 'toggle()', // in case a toggle is needed for the class named hello-1
    '[class]': 'hello-2',          // in case we want just to assign a class
  }
})
export class HelloWorldComponent {
  toggle = signal(false);
}

3) @HostBinding
Using the decorator @HostBinding is possible to achieve the same behavior, but per documentation

Always prefer using the host property over @HostBinding and
@HostListener. These decorators exist exclusively for backwards
compatibility.

